# __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__ is not defined import Jquery with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I have tried severally without luck importing jquery to global scope using webpack with below methods , but all throw errors :

Try 1 : Expose Loader

Used it in my webpack.config as below

```
{ test: require.resolve('jquery'), loader: 'expose?$!expose?jQuery' },
```

Throws error $ is not defined when i console.log(typeof $)

Try 2 : Webpack ProvidePlugin

Used it in my webpack.config as below

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      '$': 'jquery',
      'jQuery': 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    })
  ]
```

throws error **WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY** is not defined when hot-reloading

Am using vue.js V2

Comment: there is an open discussion on webpack github project: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/426